# siunitx in apparent conflict with cmbright

Tags: siunitx

I have recently upgraded from an old machine on which I use `siunitx` with the `cmbright` package to get a sans serif font. However, this produces a slightly bold(er) font for the unit now which should not be the case:
[image: siunitxs slightly bolder font]

I hope I have implemented the necessary improvements of my code, namely exchanging `SI` by `qty`. So I run the following code with pdflatex (mwe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
\qty{5}{\m} vs. 5m
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`siunitx` detects that you are using a sans serif font and switches to `\mathsf`, which cmbright doesn't set up and so is still `cmss`. You can force siunitx to use `\mathrm` again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{unit-font-command = \mathrm}} 
\usepackage{cmbright}
\begin{document}
\qty{5}{\m} vs. 5m
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just declare `\mathsf` to be what it should. For some reasons, `cmbright` fails to declare it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{\familydefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\qty{5}{\m} vs. 5m

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like (almost) a bug in cmbright. I chose Ulrike's answer since it seems less technical, hope you understand:)

Comment: @fborchers No problem! The declaration is important in order not to have surprises when `\mathsf` is used, maybe porting some other code.